# How do I use DI with many different implementations of an interface with a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface

I am trying to create an aggregator that can loop through several implementations of an interface (`IContentReader`) with a generic type that is constrained to another interface (`IContent`). Each implementation of the `IContentReader` will use a different implementation of the 'IContent` interface. This does not appear to work with DI. I am kind of at a loss as to how to do this.

My requirements will expand over time to include new games each with their own readers and content. How can I make this an DI friendly solution?

Here is the interface with the generic type:

```
public interface IContentReader<TContent> where TContent: IContent
{    
    IList<TContent> Content { get; }

    void Read(string file);
}
```

Content interface:

```
public interface IContent
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

This is an example of the aggregator that will loop through the implementations:

```
public class ContentReaderAggregator : IContentReaderAggregator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IContentReader<IContent>> _readers;


    public ContentReaderAggregator(IEnumerable<IContentReader<IContent>> readers)
    {
        _readers = readers;
    }


    public void Read(string file)
    {
        foreach (var reader in _readers)
            reader.Read(file);
    }
}
```

An example implementation of a type of content and a reader:

```
public class Game1Content : IContent
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Game1ContentReader : IContentReader<Game1Content>
{
    public IList<Game1Content> Content { get; }
    
    public void Read(string file)
    {
        //Read implementation code
    }
}
```

The compiler error I get when I try to create a collection of the `IContentReader` implementations is [CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503))

I understand this conversion error for the most part, so I'm more asking what I am doing wrong from a philosophical/design pattern point of view.

Comment: Would it help to make `IContentReader` [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)?

Comment: BTW, why is `IContent` an interface? Are you planning on implementing that getter in more than one way?

Comment: @MarkSeemann to your first question, I'm not sure, but thanks for the link! Will read up on it.
To the second question: I removed some of the complexity from `IContent` for brevity. For my actual case, I believe an interface is warranted. Is your question about implementation that I should have used an abstract class instead because Interfaces are behavioral signatures?

Comment: No, I'm asking because the inner polymorphism is probably what's giving you problems, hence the question about covariance. If `IContent` contains only data (i.e. getters and setters) there's no reason to make it polymorphic. If it truly contains polymorphic *behaviour* (i.e. methods), it's another matter.

Comment: As written, you could push `void Read(string file)` up to an `IContentReaderBase` (non-generic) interface and use that, but maybe you have other requirements?